# Clone PR using java program or JGIT

Tags: java, git, github, bitbucket, jgit

I wanted to clone a specific pull request using java JGit API. Does anyone have an idea about it? Or any alternate way to clone Pull request using java program.

Let's consider below is the code to checkout or clone PR from GitHub,

```
1: git clone https://github.com/deepak-kumbhar/spring-boot-logging-example.git
2. cd PROJECT_NAME
3. git fetch origin pull/1/head:pr-1 (Where 1 is number or PR)
4. git checkout pr-1 (To activate the PR)
```

The same functionality I want using JGit. Does anyone have an idea about it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as described at https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

The basic steps for pulling PR #6 from https://github.com/github/testrepo/pull/6/commits are

```
    System.out.println("Cloning from " + REMOTE_URL + " to " + localPath);
    try (Git result = Git.cloneRepository()
            .setURI(REMOTE_URL)
            .setDirectory(localPath)
            .setProgressMonitor(new SimpleProgressMonitor())
            .call()) {
        // Note: the call() returns an opened repository already which needs to be closed to avoid file handle leaks!
        System.out.println("Having repository: " + result.getRepository().getDirectory());

        FetchResult fetchResult = result.fetch()
                .setRemote(REMOTE_URL)
                .setRefSpecs("+refs/pull/6/head:pr_6")
                .call();

        System.out.println("Result when fetching the PR: " + fetchResult.getMessages());

        Ref checkoutRef = result.checkout()
                .setName("pr_6")
                .call();

        System.out.println("Checked out PR, now printing log, it should include two commits from the PR on top");

        Iterable<RevCommit> logs = result.log()
                .call();
        for (RevCommit rev : logs) {
            System.out.println("Commit: " + rev /* + ", name: " + rev.getName() + ", id: " + rev.getId().getName() */);
        }
    }
```

See the ready-to-run snippet at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CheckoutGitHubPullRequest.java